Assigning Datetime value to a variable in SSIS for incremental loading the data by maximum created datetime
I get the maximum created datetime from the following query and then it is assigned to a variable
SELECT  [CompanyID],
MAX([MPDItemsCreatedDATETIME]) AS max_created_date,
MAX([MPDItemsUpdatedDATETIME]) AS max_updated_date
FROM [DataWarehouse_Dev].[Inventory].[DimItem] WHERE CompanyID != 'NA'
GROUP BY CompanyID
ORDER BY CompanyID

Then I use the following query to get the data where created the data is greater than the maximum created datetime
" SELECT ["+@[User::DatabaseName]+"].[dbo].[MPD_Items] WHERE CreatedDateTime >  "+@[User::objMaxCreatedDatetime]+" "

Then I get the following error.

Expression cannot be evaluated.
The data type of variable User::objMaxCreatedDatetime is not supported in an expression.
Reading the variable "User::objMaxCreatedDatetime" failed with error code 0xC00470D0.


What is the data type of the variable @[User::objMaxCreatedDatetime]? I assume it's an object? if so, the error is telling you the problem; your first query returns a dataset; you  can't inject an object as a scalar value. You need to iterate through your dataset, and then SECURELY inject the database name and parametrise the date value. Or, for the database, it would likely be better to parametrise the database name (initial catalog) in the connection manager.

It is a datetime. Object result is taken as a datetime variable naming as a objMaxCreatedDatetime

You can't just inject a datetime value into a string value. Parameterise your query, and the error will go away. And don't use confusing names for your variables. If your variable is a date and time value, don't prefix it obj. That's like have a integer value called dtMyNumber.

I have parameterized it to a datetime but I get the above error

That isn't parametrisation, that's injection. Parameterisation would have the query be WHERE CreatedDateTime > ?;.

Here I use foreachloop container to get the maximum created data values in Product tables from 5 databases
